# It is posibble to use multiple attachment name in AttachOne?

Tags: laravel, octobercms

Is it possible to use multiple attachments name in `$AttachOne`?
For example:

```
public $attachOne = [
    'abc' => 'System\Models\File',
    'def' => 'System\Models\File'
];
```

Comment: DO you want to attach one of the items from array?

Comment: yep, to store at 'System\Models\File'

Comment: Why not have a separate array and select one from that using array_random? Btw, do all keys have same value ''System\Models\File''?

Comment: Im not understand what you saying, sorry

Comment: Or maybe i have to create new model files to attachOne for only 'def' ?

Comment: its fine you can add as many as you like in `attachOne` relation
- 'profilePic' => 'System\Models\File',
- 'avatarPic'  => 'System\Models\File', .. and so on